# C# DataGrid update function

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

Currently I'm having trouble in update function for DataGrid. It is unable capture my input in the DataGrid.
Is there a way to capture my input by using DataGrid? Because most of the information internet using GridView which is different.

Edited:
This is a DataGrid with Update, Edit and delete function.
For example,
I select a row of data and press on Edit button, fill in the data on the selected row, then press on Update button to update the selected row information.
In this situation I am unable to capture the selected row information after edited.
So, I am unable to update the row data.

Here's the Code for HTML

```
    <asp:DataGrid ID="dgRecords" runat="server" Width="100%" DataKeyField="InsitePriceID"
                    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="5"
                    OnPageIndexChanged="dgRecords_PageIndexChanged" OnSortCommand="dgRecords_SortCommand"
                      OnDeleteCommand="dgRecords_OnDelete" OnEditCommand="dgRecords_OnEdit" OnUpdateCommand="dgRecords_OnUpdate"
                       OnCancelCommand="dgRecords_OnCancel">
                    <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="Data"></AlternatingItemStyle>
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="Data"></ItemStyle>
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="ColHeader"></HeaderStyle>
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundColumn Visible="False" DataField="InsitePriceID"></asp:BoundColumn>
                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ServicePartFrom" HeaderText="No. of Service Part (From)"
                            SortExpression="ServicePartFrom"></asp:BoundColumn>
                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ServicePartTo" HeaderText="No. of Service Part (To)"
                            SortExpression="ServicePartTo"></asp:BoundColumn>
                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="BaseAmount" HeaderText="% from Base Amount" SortExpression="BaseAmount">
                        </asp:BoundColumn>
                        <asp:EditCommandColumn ButtonType="PushButton" CancelText="Cancel" EditText="Edit"
                            UpdateText="Update"></asp:EditCommandColumn>
                        <asp:ButtonColumn ButtonType="PushButton" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:ButtonColumn>
                    </Columns>
                    <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages"></PagerStyle>
                </asp:DataGrid>
<td style="width: 1014px">
                <asp:Label ID="lbla" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblb" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblc" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
```

Code behind.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ucWScr.SetValue("Insite Price");
        pnlMsg.Visible = false;
        BindData("");
    }
}

private void BindData(string _sortExpression)
    {
        clsAdmin obj = new clsAdmin();
        int intNoRec = 0;

        DataTable tbl = obj.SearchInsitePrice();

    }

protected void dgRecords_OnUpdate(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Update")
    {
        string strInsitePriceID = dgRecords.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString();

//Error start from here

        lbla.Text = e.Item.Cells[1].Text;
        lblb.Text = e.Item.Cells[2].Text;
        lblc.Text = e.Item.Cells[3].Text;

        int intServicePartFrm = Int32.Parse(lbla.Text);
        int intServicePartTo = Int32.Parse(lblb.Text);
        int fltPercentBaseAmt = Int32.Parse(lblc.Text);

//Error ends here

        string strUserLogin = CurrentUser.UserLogin.ToString();
        DateTime dteNow = DateTime.Now;

        if (strInsitePriceID != "")
        {
            EStatus status = webform.UpdateInsitePrice(strInsitePriceID, intServicePartFrm, intServicePartTo, fltPercentBaseAmt, strUserLogin, dteNow);
            if (status != EStatus.Success) throw new Exception("Update failed.");
```

Comment: Can you specify _"unable capture my input "_? Does that mean that you get the default values there? Then i guess that you're databinding the `DataGrid` on postback. Add `if(!IsPostBack)BindDataGrid();`

Comment: Yes i get default value display from database, but I am unable to edit the row data. Something wrong with my Update function.

Comment: As i've mentioned in my last comment, i assume that you're databinding also in postbacks. Show us your `Page_Load`.

Comment: Hi Tim Schmelter, How to Databind for the updated row?
It is in BoundColumn field not textbox field, So I have no idea how to databind it and Update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by using this method.

```
protected void dgRecords_OnUpdate(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Update")
    {
        string strInsitePriceID = dgRecords.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString();
        TextBox temp, temp2, temp3;
        temp = (TextBox)e.Item.Cells[1].Controls[0];
        temp2 = (TextBox)e.Item.Cells[2].Controls[0];
        temp3 = (TextBox)e.Item.Cells[3].Controls[0];

        int intServicePartFrm = Int32.Parse(temp.Text);
        int intServicePartTo = Int32.Parse(temp2.Text);
        int fltPercentBaseAmt = Int32.Parse(temp3.Text);
```